# matchedGeometryEffect behaves strangely when target is inside a Menu label

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm working on prettying up a SwiftUI app with some animations. One place that would be nice to animate is the position of an image on a card as the card transitions states and the image becomes interactive.

The issue is that this image becomes a `Menu`, which introduces a strange animation effect. This is what it looks like in a sample project: [image: Bad Animation]

Notably, it animates correctly on deselection--the image shifts over instead of appearing from the bottom.

I know that the issue is with the `Menu` because if I pull the menu label out, the animation works fine: [image: Good Animation]

Here's simple sample code that demonstrates the problem:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selected = false
    @Namespace var animation
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(selected ? "Selected card" : "Deselected card").font(.title).padding(20)
            if selected {
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {}, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "trash")
                    })
                    Spacer()
                    Menu(content: {
                        Button("Order Now", action: {})
                        Button("Adjust Order", action: {})
                    }, label: {

                        Image(systemName: "paperplane")
                            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "send", in: animation)
                       
                    })
                }
                .padding(20)
            } else {
                HStack {
                    Text("Timestamp")
                    Spacer()
                        Image(systemName: "paperplane")
                            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "send", in: animation)

                }
            }
        }
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .padding(20)
        .background(.blue)
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 24))
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation {
                selected.toggle()
            }
        }
        .padding(20)
    }
}
```

To "fix" it, simply move the `Image` out of the Menu label and see that it animates correctly.

I've tried several workarounds to fix this issue:

1. Making the "deselected" arm use a `Menu` with `.disabled` and then moving the `matchedGeometryEffect` to the Menu itself. This *works*, but isn't exactly what I want because in my actual use case, the Menu is an `HStack` of the image and a text label, and [text labels do not behave nicely with `matchedGeometryEffect`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70298791/is-it-possible-to-resize-text-with-matched-geometry-effect)
2. Using `.overlay` and/or `ZStack` to hide the menu underneath the image. This also works okay, but means that when clicking on the menu image, the image does not gray out the way it normally would.
3. I've looked into making the image just be a button and creating the menu without using `Menu`. This seems gross.

Any thoughts on how best to approach this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest avoiding `MatchedGeometryEffect` here and move the use of `selected` inside of the `HStack`.  Use `.disabled(selected)` on the `Menu` to enable/disable its usage as a `Menu`.  Since `MatchedGeometryEffect` is no longer used, using text with the `Menu` title is no longer an issue.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selected = false
    @Namespace var animation
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                Text("Selected card").opacity(selected ? 1 : 0)
                Text("Deselected card").opacity(selected ? 0 : 1)
            }.font(.title).padding(20)
            HStack {
                if selected {
                    Button(action: {}, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "trash")
                    })
                } else {
                    Text("Timestamp")
                }
                Spacer()
                Menu(content: {
                    Button("Order Now", action: {})
                    Button("Adjust Order", action: {})
                }, label: {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "paperplane")
                        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text("Not").opacity(selected ? 1 : 0)
                            Text("Menu").opacity(selected ? 0 : 1)
                        }
                    }
                    
                }).disabled(selected)
            }
            .padding(selected ? 20 : 0)
            
        }
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .padding(20)
        .background(.blue)
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 24))
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation {
                selected.toggle()
            }
        }
        .padding(20)
    }
}
```

---

[image: Demo running in simulator]