# Different Text and Frame Animations with MatchedGeometryEffect due to Text resizing

Tags: swift, swiftui, matchedgeometryeffect

I will provide simplified case.

I change my `Text` font size during a transition by `.matchedGeometryEffect`. I animate the text resizing with `.onAppear` modifiers and it works fine. However, during the animation, as the text moves to its new position, text animation is not same as its frame animation, the text appears to be out of its boundaries, not animating in tandem with its frame, even though I apply same default animations everywhere.

[image]

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    
    @Namespace var namespace
    @State var move = false
    @State var font: CGFloat = 15
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Button("Move") {
                withAnimation {
                    move.toggle()
                }
            }
            
            if !move {
                Text("Some Text")
                    .font(.system(size: font))
                    .padding()
                    .background(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                            .foregroundStyle(.blue)
                    )
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "title", in: namespace)
                    .transition(.scale(scale: 1)) // Stops a fading out bug

                    .frame(width: 120)
                
                    .onAppear {
                        withAnimation {
                            font = 15
                        }
                    }
                
            } 
            else {
                Text("Some Text")

                    .font(.system(size: font))

                    .padding()
                    .background(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                            .foregroundStyle(.blue))

                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "title", in: namespace)
                                
                    .transition(.scale(scale: 1)) // Stops a fading out bug

                    .offset(x: 50, y: 200)
                    .frame(width: 120)

                    .onAppear {
                        withAnimation {
                            font = 20
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    SwiftUIView()
}
```

The issue does not occur if I do not use `.matchedGeometryEffect` (not switching views) or if I don't resize the text during the transition. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73102497/17597134) approach using an animatable modifier which animates fine, but text reorganisation (if the number of text lines changes) doesn't animate during transition, and there is an issue if the animation is reversed before completion.

Is there a way to achieve the desired effect with `.matchedGeometryEffect`, where the text's animation is in tandem with its frame animation? Any guidance or hints are highly appreciated.

**UPD** when I test on physical device (iPhone XS Max) and press "Move", `Text` increases font and doesn't even move to new location until animation finishes, while blue rectangle does move. The reverse animation (after pressing the button again) works fine:

[image]

Comment: Try adding ```.drawingGroup()``` to both views, immediately after ```.background``` and before ```.matchedGeometryEffect```.

Comment: Good guess, would work for simple views, but unfortunately in my actual case I have complex views with certain gestures and applying .drawingGroup cause a lot of trouble

Comment: I think the reason why the animation is not synchronized is because there are two animations happening. The first is the change of view (triggered by the ```move``` flag), the second is the font change, which is triggered in ```.onAppear```. The synchronization is better if you change font size in the same block as toggling the view, but then the height of the blue rectangle is seen to jump when the text wraps to 2 lines. Another workaround is to delay the move transition by changing it to ```withAnimation(.default.delay(0.25))```, but I wouldn't say it's a great solution.