Animating Text() Across screens with Matched Geometry Effect
I'm trying to have a matched geometry effect where a Text() is being animated across two different screens/views.  I want the animation to continuously interpolate the texts size between the source and target... basically what anyone would expect/want.
This single-screen example works (it at least satisfies the above):
import SwiftUI

struct MatchedGeometryExample: View {
    @Namespace private var animationNamespace
    @State private var isExpanded = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()

            HStack{
                Text("Example Text")
                    .font(isExpanded ? .largeTitle : .body)
                    .offset(x: isExpanded ? 100 : 0)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "exampleText", in: animationNamespace)
                    .padding()
                
                    .background(.pink)
            }

            Spacer()

            Button("Toggle") {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5)) {
                    isExpanded.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MatchedGeometryExample_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MatchedGeometryExample()
    }
}

But when I try to do it across screens, such as this example:
import SwiftUI

enum NavTarget {
    case main
    case subScreen
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    
    
    
    @Namespace private var animationNamespace
    
    @State var nav: NavTarget = .main
    
    var body: some View {
        
        //MatchedGeometryExample()
        
        
        switch nav {
        case .main:
            SourceScreen(nav: $nav, animationNamespace: animationNamespace)
        case .subScreen:
            TargetScreen(nav: $nav, animationNamespace: animationNamespace)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}


import SwiftUI

struct SourceScreen: View {
    
    @Binding var nav: NavTarget
    var animationNamespace: Namespace.ID

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()

            Text("Example Text")
                .font(.body)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "exampleText", in: animationNamespace)
                //.padding()

            Spacer()

            Button("Toggle") {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5)) {
                    nav = .subScreen
                }
            }
        }
    }
}




struct TargetScreen: View {

    @Binding var nav: NavTarget
    var animationNamespace: Namespace.ID
    

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()

            Text("Example Text")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "exampleText", in: animationNamespace)
                //.padding()

            Spacer()

            Button("Toggle") {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5)) {
                    nav = .main
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

It does not animate properly, and it is doing something weird.  I can't include a video, but to describe it, it is cross-fading the two texts, and also seems to be placing the target in a frame that is too small during the animation causing visual truncation with the ellipses "..."
I think the answer might involve some combination of drawingGroup(), scaleEffect(), and/or frame(..) but I can't figure it out.
Also, I'm pretty sure it could be accomplished by defining a fixed frame size to both the source and target, but that is not ideal because it would break easily if we changed font, or actual string content, since we don't actually know what size the text is.

This won't work - the parent view of the Text is destroyed when nav changes. The cross-fade is the default transition animation between SourceScreen and TargetScreen. How about moving the Text up the hierarchy, making it a sibling of the two screens?

Have you run this in Xcode? (not that that is expected of anyone)... I'm pretty sure the matched geo is working as such.  I verified by replacing the text with a circle and it work properly

Of course I did run in Xcode, and I replaced the texts with circles too. And the effect is that their geometries don't match at all.

If you remove all the text-specific modifiers and put a frame on the circle (after the match geo effect) it "works"

Dont waste your time on this I found a similar question and also found a solution so I'll be putting an answer on it woohoo! (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70298791/is-it-possible-to-resize-text-with-matched-geometry-effect) this message  ( and question) will self destruct
